# Ubuntu 22.04 change default file manager

Tags: gnome, filemanager, default-programs

Just installed Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome. I want to change the default file manager to one I installed (specifically [PCManFM](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PCManFM)). I cannot believe it is so complicated, I have tried with some options I found here and there but without success so far.

If a Gnome developer ever reads this: please add the option in the settings menu together with all other default applications.

Comment: `xdg-mime default pcmanfm-qt.desktop inode/directory`

Comment: Does not seem to work. Do I have to stat a new session?

Answer (score 0):

After running this in the terminal:

```
xdg-mime default pcmanfm.desktop inode/directory application/x-gnome-saved-search
```

the default file manager was partially changed. I say *partially* because when I use the search box in the activities area now it opens things in the new file manager, also when I double click something in the desktop. However some apps like Firefox still use Nautilus when you click "show in folder" in the downloads box, for example.

Comment: maybe snap related?